# Invalid Syntax on 'column name' When Dropping Rows based on Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm dropping rows based on column values. My df contains two specific columns that I'm filtering: ['Exclude', 'Lost Flag']. Both columns contain binary values. I dropped all rows where "Exclude" was 1 via:

```
df = df[df.Exclude !=1]
```

All is well. However, when I tried to do the same thing with "Lost Flag":

```
df = df[df.Lost Flag !=1]
```

I get SyntaxError on the column name. I've triple checked the column name, tried underscore, no space, and tried escaping the space using ``. Then I tried pd.query:

```
df = df.query('Lost Flag !=1')
```

And I got the same syntax error. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Lots of operations don't support names with spaces, just like the dot notation.
In any case, it's probably better to use df["col name"] than the dot notation for columns

Comment: I would agree that it's always better to use `df['col name']` for accessing columns, whether there are spaces or not. Unless you have space limitations on your script file for some unknown reason, changing to this notation can help resolve a whole lot of issues I've come across

Answer (score 2):

try with a ` for space:

```
df.query('`Lost Flag`!=1')
```

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

> ```
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 6),
> ...                    'B': range(10, 0, -2),
> ...                    'C C': range(10, 5, -1)})
> >>> df
>    A   B  C C
> 0  1  10   10
> 1  2   8    9
> 2  3   6    8
> 3  4   4    7
> 4  5   2    6
>
> For columns with spaces in their name, you can use backtick quoting.
>
> >>> df.query('B == `C C`')
>    A   B  C C
> 0  1  10   10
> ```

Comment: @awhit may be a pandas upgrade is required to `0.25.0` , i just tried df.query("`C C`!=10") and it works

Comment: +1 wow.... this is why I come to SO... and why I should read completely the "What's new" in every pandas release.   OI just learned about "back ticking"  nice.

Comment: @ScottBoston I am glad one of my answer helped you since many of your's helped me:)  bdw, it may interest you to know that `1.0` is [coming soon](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/milestone/16) :)